Complete Sufficient Statistis with pdf $f(x;\theta) =\theta(1+x)^{-(1+\theta)}$
[Bain Problem 31  p.356] Let $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n$ be a random sample of size $n$ from a distribution with pdf
$$f(x;\theta) = \left\{\begin{array}{rr} \theta(1+x)^{-(1+\theta)}, &x>0 \\ 0, &x\le 0 \end{array} \right ..$$
Find a complete sufficient statistics for $\theta$.

Here is my approach.
Note that
\begin{align*}f(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n;\theta) &= \prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i;\theta) = \theta^n\left (\prod_{i=1}^n (1+x_i) \right )^{-(1+\theta)}.\end{align*}
By factorisation theorem for $g(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)=1$ and $h(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n;\theta) =\theta^n \left (\prod_{i=1}^n (1+x_i)\right )^{-(1+\theta)}$, therefore $U= \prod_{i=1}^n (1+X_i)$ sufficient statistics for $\theta$. But, key answer from book tell $\ln \prod_{i=1}^n (1+X_i)$ sufficient statistics for $\theta$. Is it sufficient statistics for $\theta$ not always unique (or infinitely many)?
So far, I have done nothing to prove $U=(1+X_1)(1+X_2)\cdots (1+X_n)$ it's complete statistics for $\theta$. I found pdf of $1+X_i$, but I don't know how to find pdf of $U$ (of course to compute $E[F(U)]$).

For your first question, you are right: both are sufficient statistics, and in general, sufficient statistics are not unique. For example, if $S(x)$ is sufficient, so is $2S(x)$.
